# jQuery children().fadeOut() then execute a single function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery function that looks like this:

```
$.get(urlCall, function (data) {
    $('#divId').children().fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $('#divId').append(data);
        $('#divId').fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

The problem is that it is calling the append and fadeIn lines once for EACH child under '#divId'. I was expecting the line

```
$('#divId').children().fadeOut("slow", function() {
```

to fade out all children and then execute the function() a single time. But since it's executing the function() once for each child, I'm appending a lot of lines that I don't want appended.

I'm sure that there must be a way to say, "fade out all children, and then do X once", but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use [.promise()](http://api.jquery.com/promise/)

```
$('#divId').children().fadeOut("slow").promise().done(function() {
    $('#divId').append(data);
    $('#divId').fadeIn("slow");
});
```

> The .promise() method returns a dynamically generated Promise that is
>   resolved once all actions of a certain type bound to the collection,
>   queued or not, have ended.
>
> By default, type is "fx", which means the returned Promise is resolved
>   when all animations of the selected elements have completed.

## For the the downvoter

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y3SMq/)

Comment: @Kayo - There is only way to combat this. Upvote all the things.

Comment: @Arun - So promise will only take action once after the entire set has been handled, and then done will ensure that the animation from fading is complete before the callback is executed?

Comment: @TravisJ yes it is.... `Promise is resolved when all animations of the selected elements have completed`

Answer (score 1):

Why not just separate the fading and the appending?  So it would be

```
$.get(urlCall, function (data) {
    $('.someElement').each(function(){
         $('.fadeElement').fadeIn();

    });

    $('.otherElement').append(data)
});
```

Comment: This doesn't help anything. The `.append()` call won't wait for the `.fadeIn()` calls (which are asynchronous animations) to finish, which is what the OP asked for

Comment: Then make the call synchronous

Answer (score 1):

The only way to reliably do this is to make your own function that keeps track of how many animations have completed, and compares against the number of original animations. Something like:

```
var target = $("#divId"),
    children = target.children();

$("#trigger").on("click", function () {
    toggleFadeAll(children, function () {
        $("#message").fadeToggle();
    });
});

function toggleFadeAll(els, callback) {
    var counter = 0,
        len = els.length;
    els.fadeToggle(function () {
        if (++counter === len) {
            callback.call(null);
        }
    });
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/jbE3C/

(this will obviously need to be adjusted based on what animating you actually want to happen)

The `toggleFadeAll` will call the callback provided when all `fadeToggle` animations have completed.

**Using `.promise()` fails (doesn't execute the desired callback at the right point in time) when there are other animations possibly happening to the elements.**